# Impact Force by this pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I would like to ask a very basic physics question which I am struggling to find the answer to.

What would be the impact force when an object is attached to a piece of rope and pulled to a certain height then swing down to hit a wall?

[image]

Comment: You need to know how long the impact takes to answer this question.  See Figure 9.7 and the related example problem in the following link: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/9-2-impulse-and-collisions

Comment: From your question we can only figure out the kinetic energy right before the collision. The force then depends on the deformation / the distance it takes for the kinetic energy to be converted to heat.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple, unequivocal answer to your question. The simplest answer is: 'it depends!'

Depends on what? It depends on the 'hardness' of both the object and the wall and the elasticity of the collision.

Imagine the wall to be hard and inflexible but the object to be made of a soft, fluffy spongy material. The latter, on impact, will behave like a soft spring so that the impact force, here *idealised* to a [Hookean spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law#Formal_definition), will be low:

$$F_{impact}=k\Delta x$$

where $k$ is the spring constant and $\Delta x$ the deformation of the object.

But if the object is stiffer then $k$ will larger and so will $F_{impact}$.

The same reasoning applies to the wall: a soft, absorbent wall will lead to lower impact forces than a hard, unyielding one.

**A Little Math...**

1. **Firstly,** assume the collision to be fully elastic, so the conditions are:

- Collision is elastic
- Wall is hard, inflexible and immovable

Change in potential energy given by:

$$\Delta U=mgl(1-\cos\theta)$$
Conservation of energy:
$$\Delta U=W\tag{1}$$
Work $W$ done on object:
$$W=\int_0^{\Delta x}F(x)\text{d}x=\int_0^{\Delta x}kx\text{d}x=\frac12 k \Delta x^2$$
Conservation of energy:
$$mgl(1-\cos\theta)=\frac12 k\Delta x^2$$
So that:
$$\Delta x=\sqrt{\frac{2 mgl(1-\cos\theta)}{k}}$$
And:
$$F_{impact}=k\Delta x$$
So that:
$$\boxed{F_{impact}=\sqrt{2 kmgl(1-\cos\theta)}}$$
So $F_{impact} \propto \sqrt{k}$. Of course $F_{impact}$ is the **peak** of the force acting on the object during the impact (and the reaction force on the wall). Once the peak value has reached the impact force diminishes, until the object's acceleration has reached $\text{zero}$.

2. **Secondly**, if the impact is inelastic, then:

$$\Delta U=W_{el}+E_{inel}$$
where $E_{inel}$ are 'lost energies' $^\dagger$ (permanent deformation, heat, sound etc.)

$$mgl(1-\cos\theta)-E_{inel}=\frac12 k\Delta x^2$$
$$\boxed{F_{impact}=\sqrt{2 kmgl(1-\cos\theta)-E_{inel}}}$$

So the impact is lower in the case of an inelastic collision.

$[\dagger]$ no energy is ever truly lost but the energy we're talking about here cannot be returned to the system. It's still proportionate the $k$ but in a reduced way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would delta X be the deformation of the object or the wall? Let’s say the object bounced back and at the same time made a dent on the wall.

Comment: $F_{impact}=k\Delta x$ is of course an *idealisation*, as no wall or object behaves as a *perfect* Hookean spring. Also, if a dent is made in the wall that means the impact was very inelastic (kinetic energy was lost) and this will *reduce* the impact force. So $\Delta x$ can be the deformation of the wall, the object or even both.